# Finding the general function that satisfies this property

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I've been playing around with some introductory examples in my functional
analysis course, and I came across.

Given $X = \mathbb{R} \setminus \{0,1,2\},$
I want to find all functions $f: X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that
$f(x) + f(1-\frac{2}{x}) = 1+x.$

I thought about analyzing this problem from a derivative format, i.e.
$f'(x) = 1 - f'(1-\frac{2}{x}) + \frac{2}{x^2}.$

However, I am wondering if there is another property of $f(x)$ that I should
be considering, namely what I should be doing about the $2$ missing from the
domain for $f(x)$. Any recommendations on this problem?